# Very old VB3 (20+ years ago) running on a Box Win7 32bit Prof, need DAO Access 2.0 MDB support

Tags: ms-access, components, installation, dao, b3

About 20+ years ago I developed a VB3 app (ie 16bit) for a friends manufacturing firm that used Access 2.0 MDB file as a back-end database. He has gone through multiple PC and managed to get it working on each iteration, but on the latest we cant seem to get the exe to open the MDB file (ERROR: invalid Format).

We are running on a VBox Win7 32bit platform (previously it was working on a real box with similar setup, but that died)

I am guessing (i haven't used VB3 for 20+ years) we are missing some dependent DLL and/or registration(s). I am hoping someone can point me to an install for the missing component? DAO?

I have installed MS Access 1.0 (couldn't read the MDB) and MS Access 2.0 (CAN read the MDB).

Another possibility, if someone has a small utility app that reads MDB files, with a setup EXE, that may install/register the necessary components for my old exe to work. We are getting desperate as this app is core to his business and he is a close and obviously long term friend, that can not justify/afford the redevelopment of the app from scratch; its very uniquely tailored and complex, and works when it can read the dB.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.found it.

There is a compatibility layer install exe, that handles the install of all the necessary files.

comlyr.exe
ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/softlib/mslfiles/COMLYR.EXE

I actually got it from somewhere else.